# Как выйти из бесконечной рекурсии n=2, чтобы выводились правильные значения функции, с++

Tags: c++

Дана такая функция, коэффициенты a,b,x,y,p,q определены в коде, n - это 
  аргумент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для n = 1 и n = 0 код работает, выводит что нужно, но дальше нет. При n=2 будет бесконечная рекурсия, от которой нужно как-то избавиться.

Помогите исправить код, чтобы выводило значение функции правильно при любых n

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int a = 0, b = 0, x = 0, y = 0, p = 0, q = 0, k = 20;

double F(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return b;
    if (n == 0)
        return a;
    if (n == 2)
        return (F(n / 2) * x) / (1 - y);
    if (n % 2 == 0 && n != 2)
        return ((F(2*n) - y * F(n + 1)) / x);
    if (n % 2 != 0)
        return ((F(2*n + 1) - q * F(n + 1)) / p);
    return F(n);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    a = k;
    b = 2*k + 1;
    x = 3 * k + 2;
    y = k * k + 2 * k - 1;
    p = 5 * k - 1;
    q = k * k + 11 * k - 3;
    cout << "Введите аргумент n: ";
    cin >> n;
    F(n);
    cout << F(n)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А вы умеете пользоваться отладчиком ? Ваша проблема решается по щелчку пальца.

Comment: Вы бы функцию, раз уж она выводит неверные значения (иначе заем просить *"чтобы выводило значение функции правильно при 
любых n"*?) дли не только кодом, а все же ее математическую формулировку.

Comment: Да, исина где-то рядом, но я не знаю, я в программировании новичок, учусь, саму функцию добавил, сразу почему-то не получилось загрузить, правил

Comment: А ведь ваше решение решает совершенно другую задачу. А где ваши собственные наработки?

Comment: Я знаю, что после return написано не то, что должно быть, условия вроде правильные, а вот что под них написать, чтобы выйти из бесконечной рекурсии и вывести значение функции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Условие n==2 абсолютно лишнее.
2. Выход из рекурсии у Вас происходит при n==0, n==1, но при n>2 у Вас происходит рекурсивный вызов функции с увеличенным параметром, тогда как он должен уменьшаться, чтобы двигаться в сторону выхода.
3. Вы не до конца верно поняли задачу. В задаче Вам дана не функция от **n**, а функция от **некоего z**, в то время, как выражения: **0, 1, 2n, 2n+1** накладывают требования на **z**, при выполнении которых должно быть реализовано соответствующее вычисление. Например: Строку **F(2n) = x•F(n) + y•F(n+1)** следует читать следующим образом - **F(z)** при четном z вычисляется как сумма **x•F(z/2)** и **y•F((z/2)+1)**
4. Последний **return**, который, в принципе, никогда не сработает, написан у Вас так, что просто вызовет зацикливание функции, так как запись **return F(n)** при том, что n у Вас - входной параметр, произвела бы рекурсивный вызов функции с тем же параметром, что получила вызывающая функция.

Comment: Юрий, я переделал на функцию z, да система в общем то о ней, но условие z=2 должно быть, иначе никак не выйти, вот что получилось, работает, но есть предупреждение: ругается на 1-у: арифметическое переполнение: использование оператора - на байтовом значении 4 и приведение результата к байтовому значению 8.

Comment: @ДжонСноу Если Вас устроил мой ответ, будьте добры - отметьте  его галочкой слева.

Comment: Да, конечно, вы натолкнули в нужном направлении, я посчитал вручную для 3, и у меня совпало до сотой доли

Answer (score 0):

Я бы записал ее так:

```
double F(unsigned int n,
         double a, double b,
         double x, double y,
         double p, double q) {
    return
        (n == 0) ? a :
        (n == 1) ? b :
        (n == 2) ? x*F(1,a,b,x,y,p,q)/(1-y) :
        (n%2 == 0) ? x*F(n/2,a,b,x,y,p,q)+y*F(n/2+1,a,b,x,y,p,q) :
        p*F((n-1)/2,a,b,x,y,p,q)+q*F((n+1)/2,a,b,x,y,p,q);
    }
```

Но если `n` может быть достаточно большим - то лучше применить мемоизацию.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int z,a = 0, b = 0, x = 0, y = 0, p = 0, q = 0, k = 18;
double F(int z)
{
if (z == 1)
    return b;
if (z == 0)
    return a;
if (z % 2 == 0 && z != 2)//если z четное
    return (x*F(z/2) + y * F ((z/2) +1));
if (z == 2)
    return ((x*F(z/2))/(1-y));
if (z % 2 != 0)//если z нечетное
    return (p*F((z-1)/2)+q*F((z+1)/2));
}  
int main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
a = k;
b = 2*k + 1;
x = 3 * k + 2;
y = k * k + 2 * k - 1;
p = 5 * k - 1;
q = k * k + 11 * k - 3;
cout << "Введите аргумент z: ";
cin >> z;
F(z);
cout << F(z)<<endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да, я понял, откуда у Вас взялось отдельное ограничение на z=2, извините, был не прав :))  Будьте добры, напишите полностью сообщение об ошибке. Возможно, у Вас 1 в выражении 1-y воспринимается, как int64. Попробуйте написать (int)1-y